# Direct speech to reported speech with Hush!

Tags: grammar, interjections, indirect-speech, narration

Please change the sentence from direct speech to reported speech. I cannot solve this problem. Can anyone solve this?

He said, "HUSH! The headmaster is coming."

Comment: Change it to what, exactly?

Comment: Exclamatory sentence : direct to indirect

Comment: Do you mean change it from a direct quote to reported speech?

Comment: HUSH, he warned(whispered etc. because the Headmaster was coming.

Comment: "HUSH" (would it be capitalised, which seems to indicate shouting?) is an interjection (albeit usually a quiet one). They don't move conveniently into indirect speech. 'He requested silence in the typical informal way, warning us that ...'

Comment: Well, if that's what you want, then it would be something like: *He hushed them because the headmaster was coming."

Comment: What is the problem? As it stands it is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> He told them to hush because the Headmaster was coming.

By the way, here in the UK children (and most adults) don't use the word "hush" in conversation any more. "Shut up" is much more colloquial. "Hush" may still be current in other parts of the world.

Comment: This was pretty much my answer before I edited it: *He said for them to hush because the headmaster was coming.* Then when I assumed that the OP was engaging in homework or some similar activity that would require 'going by the rules,' as most ESL questions require, I changed my answer to abide by the normal rules of converting d.s. to i.s./r.s.

Answer (score -2):

**He exclaimed with command to silence that the headmaster was coming.**

It is technically correct, if not idiomatic.

For a guideline, see [this page](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/changing-exclamatory-sentence-reported-speech/) or [this one](http://studyandexam.com/indirect-speech-imperative-exclamatory.html).